# JMETER recording issue with VPN

Tags: jmeter

We are trying to record UI based Application in JMETER for the public network and made proxy settings accordingly in Firefox browse with valid certificate.

But with VPN, we could not be able to record that UI application and we are getting below error.

[image]

we made changes to proxy configuration too as suggested by our infra team in Firefox browser and in JMeter tool, but we could not able to record at all public network UI application.

Answer (score 0):

There should not be any issue with recording the applications which are being the VPN because Java relies on operating system [routing mechanisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing) in order to find the best way to the system under test.

Just make sure to start the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) after connecting to the VPN and don't forget to import JMeter's certificate into your browser.

In case of any problems check what's in [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) - it should contain the failure reason.

Also be aware of an alternative way of recording a JMeter test: [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium), in that case you won't have to worry about proxies, certificates and VPNs.